# Word or phrase for "exceptionally skilled in mêlée combat"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or a short phrase describing someone as particularly skilled or gifted, or very likely to hit one's opponent, in [mêlée](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e) (single) combat.

However,

- It mustn't be specific to just one kind of weapon.
- It mustn't be about pure physiological traits such as strength or speed.
- It mustn't be extremely colloquial (i.e. "badass" won't do).

You could say I want the mêlée version of *marksman* — which you could use for throwing knives, shooting a bow, or firing a gun.

To put it as the "blank" a sentence:

> You are quite the ________ - you took him down before he knew ow what hit him.

which should be the equivalent of

> You are quite the marksman - you got him in one shot.

Comment: Is this intended for a digital game? "Badass" might capture the spirit, to say nothing of the user base's natural vocabulary...

Comment: You could look at old AD&D rules for the level names of various physically-oriented classes :o) [actually, that might be a serious suggestion].

Comment: @Rob_Ster: Maybe... :-)  but, it would be a respectable game, so something less colloquial

Comment: @einpoklum - oxymoron

Comment: If we could say you want the melee version of "Marksman" - which you could use for throwing knives, shooting a bow or firing a gun - then you'd clearly be trying to use ELU as a dictionary or thesaurus… 

Either way, what difference are you trying to make between *combat* and *melee*, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I mean melee in the sense of close-quarter, one-on-one combat rather than any other kind.

Comment: Oh, right… that sounds like *single combat* and not like, for instance, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=melee&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=melee&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j0l2.1367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @einpoklum That is pretty much the exact opposite of what a melee is. Melees (literally ‘mixed-together’) are chaotic everyone-fighting-everyone group scenarios, and a Mediaeval type of, erm, sport. One-on-one combat is not a form of melee; [this is a melee](https://www.outfit4events.com/underwood/download/images/buhurt-battle.jpg). I doubt there is a word for someone skilled at actual melee, but there may well be one for someone skilled at single combat.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in gaming circles *melee* is often used (rightly or wrongly) to mean close combat or hand-to-hand fighting, whether a confused mass or single combat.

Comment: @ChrisH I’ll readily admit I’ve never been a gamer, so I’ll take your word for it. A very peculiar usage, though, that’s quite likely to be confusing to outsiders who aren’t familiar with it.

Comment: The *mustn't be specific to one type of weapon* requirement makes it much harder. There are words like *fencer*, *swordsman*, or *sword-master* but they all refer to specific weapons. It's too much detail to go into here but there's a lot of history around who had time to train, whose combat exploits would be recorded, and what weapons were thought suitable for such people.

Comment: @ChrisH: I didn't say it has to apply to _all_ weapons. But what if you only use blunt weapons? Or what if you use knives?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet perhaps all we can take from that is that it's tricky to find the right terminology in this area

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ***ninja***;

> You are quite the ***ninja*** - you took him down before he knew ow what hit him.

Comment: @einpoklum as requested; I have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: It's the best I've gotten so far, if a bit colloquial. But if nothing better comes up I'm going to accept this.

Comment: I'll take yours. I guess there's no perfect answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas so far:

- **Adroit** - Not very combat-specific.
- **Deft** - A bit vague.
- **Beater** - Haven't seen that word used this way, but, who knows, maybe. It might imply using blunt weapons though.
- **Hard-hitter** - Focuses on part of the skills in combat rather than the whole thing.
- **Mêleur** - Someone who engages in Mêlée...
- **Wrangler** - Literally, a "bickering disputant", but figuratively, perhaps a person who does when with their bickering

(if you upvote/downvote - please explain which of these you like or dislike and why.)

Answer (score 0):

In Dungeons & Dragons lore, this was known as **specialization**. Fighter classes (barbarians, paladins, rangers, and fighters) could specialize in one weapon. It would increase the number of attacks per melee round as well as bonus attack points.

Here are some examples:

*The Weapons Master could kill with a thorn, but what he specialized in was the curved blade.*

*"My specialty is to kill with my bare hands!"*

*His specialization is with the war hammer.*

*Seth was nondescript in his social life, humble even. However, there was another side of him - few knew his secret. He thrived in battle, and he specialized in hand-to-hand melee combat."*

Comment: What you say is true, but it's just not an answer to my question. I can say "You're quite the marksman", You can't say "you're quite the specialization"...

Comment: No, but you could say *specialist*.

Comment: Stu W: I didn't downvote you, actually, I just commented. In my opinion, non-answers should not be downvoted, only proper answers which aren't any good.

Comment: Hmm, specialist. But surely, not _just_ specialist, right? Are you proposing "melee specialist"? If so, please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word "whammy", which means a serious blow, just like in the very popular phrase "double whammy". Some reference form MW:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whammy

Comment: 1. Isn't this very colloquial? 2. If I said "Cedric is a real whammy" - would you interpret that sentence as meaning he was skilled in close-quarter combat?

Answer (score 0):

**Close-fighter**.  The phrase close quarters combat was originally a nautical phrase where close referred to the closed spaces on a ship (e.g. bulkheads) where a last stand could be mounted against boarders.  See [close quarters](https://www.etymonline.com/word/close%20quarters).

Comment: "Close quarters" is a great phrase, "close-fighter" - sounds like you're a fighter, and you're closeby...

Answer (score 0):

Could the word ***[warrior](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/warrior)*** fit the bill?

> **warrior**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. (especially in former times) a brave or experienced soldier or fighter.
>      as modifier ‘the warrior heroes of ancient Greece’

Alternatively, what about ***[gladiator](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gladiator)***?

> **gladiator**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. (in ancient Rome) a man trained to fight with weapons against other men or wild animals in an arena.

Part of the reason I would throw this out here is because a **warrior** or a **gladiator** was classified as someone skilled in combat, before long range weapons were a thing (save for bow and arrow or slings). The immediate image of a **warrior** or **gladiator** is someone who fights in one-on-one combat, in an arena or coliseum. This is, of course, not an exact necessity, but it does certainly imply close-range combat, though **gladiator** certainly implies armed whereas **warrior** does not.

Comment: If only we could say "having the nature of a gladiator". Do you think "gladiatorial" sounds to weird? Warrior - I don't associate it immediately with what you would do in close-quarter combat. I mean, a bowman can be a kind of warrior, right?

Comment: "gladiatorial" certainly sounds weird but not "gladiator-like"